# Vote on comment, accept as answer in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, comments, stack-overflow

I have been using this forum for 4 days and i found it's very usefull.

However, some people misunderstood me. They think that i don't like voting on them, because they gave me the right answer.

The question is: How do i vote on someone's answer and how do i accept someone's comment as the best answer? Whoever tells me in the next 20 minutes, he gets +1

Comment: Meta-meta-question: What are we supposed to do with migrated questions like this one, where both the questioner and the answerer(s) are not registered here? Should we let them die in peace (the questions, not the users), or is there a point in trying to answer them? (*Update:* @AxGryndr is now registered here, I guess I should have kept my mouth shut.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi In theory, the poster shouldn't matter, just the question.  But yeah, kinda demotivating to be answering *only* for hypothetical future visitors.

Comment: Seems kind of wrong to take that stance because you can't convince me that this is the first time this has happened. Maybe it should be made more clear in the FAQ that Stackoverflow forum support questions belong in the meta.stackoverflow forum and to do so you have to log into the site here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I wouldn't be surprised if they register when they receive notification of the migration. One user has already done so.

Comment: @AxGryndr, welcome to Meta. I could not help noticing you said `forum` twice in your last comment. This is known to ruffle feathers sometimes around here, so maybe I should point out Stack Exchange sites are *not* forums (or maybe *fora*?)

Comment: The answer is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/

Comment: I'm sensing another "help vampire" here. I just saw someone get banned for a) asking the same question again after previous one got closed, b) asking very entry level questions, and c) being very unclear in the details. Just like Frédéric Hamidi says, this is *not* a forum site. StackExchange sites have very strict rules, and everything you do highly depends on your reputation.

Answer (score 6):

Many functions of Stackoverflow are based on your reputation. In order to be able to up vote an item your reputation has to be 15 or higher. It is most likely at the time of your first questions you did not have enough rep.

You can find out more about privileges at the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/privileges